# C++ : Forward Declaration, circular dependency, static methods

Tags: c++, static, circular-dependency

The following code, very simple, gives me this error:

> [Error] incomplete type 'C_1' used in nested name specifier

I have two classes which interact each other calling their own methods.
With this code, i can't call C1::test() because it seems it's not been found.
Any help is appreciated.

**C1.h:**

```
#ifndef C1
#define C1

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "C2.h"

class C_1{

    private:

        static C_2* c2;
    public:

        static void test();
};

#endif
```

**C1.cpp:**

```
#include "C1.h"

C_2* C_1::c2=new C_2();

void C_1::test(){

    cout << "C_1 test() method called." << endl;
    C_1::c2->test();
}
```

**C2.h:**

```
#ifndef C2
#define C2

class C_1;

class C_2{

    public:

        C_2();
        void call();

        void test();
};
#endif
```

**C2.cpp:**

```
#include "C2.h"

C_2::C_2(){}

void C_2::call(){

    C_1::test();
}

void C_2::test(){

    cout << "C_2.test() method called!"  << endl;
}
```

Comment: Add `#include "C1.h"` in `C2.cpp`.

Comment: it works now, thanks!

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi You need to accept the answer.